# How to fire a callback when using jQuery Waypoints Sticky Shortcut?

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I want to toggle a class of another element whenever `waypoint('sticky')` changes the class of the navigation bar. I was trying to fire a callback using the `handler` option, but it does not work. What could I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The callback option for Waypoints is, for some reason, "handler", so you could do it like this:

```
$.waypoint('sticky', {
    handler: function(dir) {
        //Do stuff when the user scrolls past this waypoint.
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice, I will give it a try.